# I am facing an issue in installation of some modules in PyCharm macOs

Tags: macos, matplotlib, scikit-learn, pip, pycharm

When I try to pip install scikit-learn my IDE(PyCharm) shows an error "No module named 'Cython'"
And also with matplotlib it says could not find suitabe distribution for Requirement.parse('numpy>=1.11')
I am a beginner and I don't know how to tackle this can someone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

Run first:

```
pip install Cython
```

then install scikit-learn:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

Comment: Hey, I ran pip install cython as you suggested but now when I try to install scikit-learn it is giving the message : unsupported option 'fopenmp'

Comment: try what bartleusink  suggests here: https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/3